# Error when trying to Replace Text with Image in docx header using OpenXML

Tags: c#, image, header, openxml, docx

So up until recently this code worked, and then the users changed the format of the headers.

I am using C# and OpenXML to edit the term [Sample Client] out of a header and replacing it with an Image. This has worked in the past, and actually works with some of the headers, but not others. I can't figure out why. The error I get is "Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree".

It fails on the line:

```
textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing>(element, textPlaceHolder);
```

I have found some answers mentioning that I have to use CloneNode, but I am not sure how to implement that, or why. I could use some assistance.

Sorry for the terrible code.

```
private static string AddImageToHeader(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId, int xwidth, int yheight)
    {

        LogWriter log = new LogWriter(""); 
        // Define the reference of the image.
        string results = ""; 
        var element =
             new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     //new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000, Cy = 792000L },
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = xwidth, Cy = yheight },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Header Image"
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                    "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = xwidth, Cy = yheight }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle 
                                     })
                                     )
                         )
                         { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
        
        // Search for text holder
        Text textPlaceHolder = null;
        try
        {
            
            foreach (var headerPart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
            {

                //Gets the text in headers
                textPlaceHolder = headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>().Where((x) => x.Text.Contains("Sample Client")).First();
                // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.        
                textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing>(element, textPlaceHolder);
                // Remove text place holder.
                textPlaceHolder.Remove();
                //  }
                foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
                {
                    currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("[", "");
                    currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("]", "");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results = results + "\r\n" + ex.Message.ToString();
            log.LogWrite("ERROR adding image to header: "+ex.Message.ToString());
            log.ErrorWrite("ERROR adding image to header: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            textPlaceHolder = null;
            Console.WriteLine(results);
        }
        if (textPlaceHolder == null)
        {
            log.ErrorWrite("Error textPlaceHolder is null"); 
        }
        else
        {
            var parent = textPlaceHolder.Parent;

            if (!(parent is Run))  // Parent should be a run element.
            {
                results = results + "\r\nERROR: Parent is not run\r\n";
                //log.LogWrite("ERROR: Parent is not run"); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.         
                textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing>(element, textPlaceHolder);
                // Remove text place holder.
                textPlaceHolder.Remove();
            }
        }
        return results; 

    }
```

Comment: This issue seems to be because they started using multiple headers in the document. Some of the headers are working, and some are not. I'm thinking that I am missing something to do with the multiple headers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using the same ImagePart in each of the headers. I changed my code so that it generated a new ImagePart for each header and it worked.

```
   public string AddImage2(string file, string imageLoc)
    {
        string results = "";
        if (imageLoc != "")
        {
            try
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
                {
                    //remove document protection
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentProtection dp = document.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentProtection>();

                    if (dp != null && dp.Enforcement == OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true) && dp.Edit == DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentProtectionValues.ReadOnly)
                    {
                        log.LogWrite("DOCUMENT PROTECTED");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dp.Enforcement = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(false);
                        //results = results + "\r\nDOCUMENT NOT PROTECTED\r\n";
                        //log.LogWrite("Document Not Protected"); 
                    }
                    //end doc protection removal 

                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
                    try
                    {
                        // get conversion factor for image to fit the 200 X 75 image slot
                        int iWidth = 0;
                        int iHeight = 0;
                        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageLoc))
                        {
                            iWidth = bmp.Width;
                            iHeight = bmp.Height;
                        }
                        double ratio = 1;
                        if (iHeight > 75)
                        {
                            ratio = 75 / (double)iHeight;
                        }
                        if ((iWidth * ratio) > 200)
                        {
                            ratio = 250 / (double)iWidth;
                        }
                        double conversionFactor = ratio * 9525;


                        iWidth = (int)Math.Round((decimal)iWidth * (decimal)conversionFactor);
                        iHeight = (int)Math.Round((decimal)iHeight * (decimal)conversionFactor);
                        // end conversion code

                        foreach (var headerPart in document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
                        {
                            ImagePart imagePart = headerPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
                            using (FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(imageLoc, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                imagePart.FeedData(imageStream);
                            }
                            string addImageResult = AddImageToHeader(headerPart, headerPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), iWidth, iHeight);
                            results = results + "\r\n" + addImageResult;
                            //log.LogWrite(addImageResult); 
                        }
                        results = results + "\r\nImage " + imageLoc + " added to " + file + "\r\n";
                        log.LogWrite("Image " + imageLoc + " added to " + file);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        results = results + "\r\nERROR: Unable to add Image. Exception Thrown: \r\n" + ex.Message;
                        log.LogWrite("ERROR: Unable to add Image. Exception Thrown: " + ex.Message);
                        log.ErrorWrite("ERROR: Unable to add Image. Exception Thrown: " + ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(results);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                results = results + "\r\nERROR: Document " + file + " Failed to Open\r\n Exception:\r\n" + ex.Message.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(results);
                log.LogWrite("ERROR: Document " + file + " Failed to Open\r\n Exception:" + ex.Message.ToString());
                log.ErrorWrite("ERROR: Document " + file + " Failed to Open\r\n Exception:" + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            results = "\r\nERROR: No Image to add for " + file;
            log.LogWrite("ERROR: No Image to add for " + file);
            log.ErrorWrite("ERROR: No Image to add for " + file);

        }

        return results;

    }

    private string AddImageToHeader(HeaderPart headerPart, string relationshipId, int xwidth, int yheight)
    {
        // Define the reference of the image.
        string results = "";
        var element =
             new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing(
                 new DW.Inline(
                     //new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000, Cy = 792000L },
                     new DW.Extent() { Cx = xwidth, Cy = yheight },
                     new DW.EffectExtent()
                     {
                         LeftEdge = 0L,
                         TopEdge = 0L,
                         RightEdge = 0L,
                         BottomEdge = 0L
                     },
                     new DW.DocProperties()
                     {
                         Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                         Name = "Header Image"
                     },
                     new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                         new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                     new A.Graphic(
                         new A.GraphicData(
                             new PIC.Picture(
                                 new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                     {
                                         Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                         Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                     },
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                 new PIC.BlipFill(
                                     new A.Blip(
                                         new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                             new A.BlipExtension()
                                             {
                                                 Uri =
                                                    "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                             })
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Embed = relationshipId,
                                         CompressionState =
                                         A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                     },
                                     new A.Stretch(
                                         new A.FillRectangle())),
                                 new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                     new A.Transform2D(
                                         new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                         new A.Extents() { Cx = xwidth, Cy = yheight }),
                                     new A.PresetGeometry(
                                         new A.AdjustValueList()
                                     )
                                     {
                                         Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle
                                     })
                                     )
                         )
                         { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                 )
                 {
                     DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                     EditId = "50D07946"
                 });

        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.

        // Search for text holder
        Text textPlaceHolder = null;
        try
        {
            //int iterationcount = 0;
            textPlaceHolder = headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>().Where((x) => x.Text.Contains("Sample Client")).First();
            // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.
            //var cloneElement = element.CloneNode(); 
            textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing>(element, textPlaceHolder);
            // Remove text place holder.
            textPlaceHolder.Remove();
            //  }
            //clean up brackets
            foreach (var currentText in headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>())
            {
                currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("[", "");
                currentText.Text = currentText.Text.Replace("]", "");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results = results + "\r\n" + ex.Message.ToString();
            log.LogWrite("ERROR adding image to header: "+ex.Message.ToString());
            log.ErrorWrite("ERROR adding image to header: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            textPlaceHolder = null;
            Console.WriteLine(results);
        }
        if (textPlaceHolder == null)
        {
            log.ErrorWrite("Error textPlaceHolder is null"); 
        }
        return results; 

    }
```